# why admin panel of django appears different in production version?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

first of all, I don't know whether it's only my issue or someone else have it too. my production version of django admin (which I use it in my website) looks different from what I see, when I lunch a project on my personal computer.

you can see the difference In two pictures :

[local version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLGQq.png) (127.0.0.1:8000)

[production version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNKVY.png) (mywebsite)

something that I want to mention:

My `settings.py` :

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/django_project/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

About the path:

```
root@myuser:/home/django/django_project/django_project/static# ls
admin  css  fa  fonts  img  js
```

Console log when running admin panel shows that static files related to admin panel like jquery.js does not rendering properly.

```
mywebsite.com/:12 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED
mywebsite.com/:18 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js net::ERR_ABORTED
mywebsite.com/:199 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/admin/js/change_form.js net::ERR_ABORTED
mywebsite.com/:208 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/admin/js/prepopulate_init.js net::ERR_ABORTED
mywebsite.com/:12 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
jquery.init.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.init.js:7
(anonymous) @ jquery.init.js:7
actions.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at actions.js:4
    at actions.js:144
(anonymous) @ actions.js:4
(anonymous) @ actions.js:144
prepopulate.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at prepopulate.js:2
    at prepopulate.js:39
(anonymous) @ prepopulate.js:2
(anonymous) @ prepopulate.js:39
mywebsite.com/:18 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js net::ERR_ABORTED
mywebsite.com/:200 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/admin/js/change_form.js net::ERR_ABORTED
mywebsite.com/:209 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/admin/js/prepopulate_init.js 404 (Not Found)
DateTimeShortcuts.js:277 Uncaught TypeError: django.jQuery is not a function
    at Object.addCalendar (DateTimeShortcuts.js:277)
    at init (DateTimeShortcuts.js:45)
addCalendar @ DateTimeShortcuts.js:277
init @ DateTimeShortcuts.js:45
/missing-admin-media-prefix/img/icon_calendar.gif:1 GET https://mywebsite.com/missing-admin-media-prefix/img/icon_calendar.gif 404 (Not Found)
Image (async)
HTMLElement.appendChild @ VM155:323
addCalendar @ DateTimeShortcuts.js:224
init @ DateTimeShortcuts.js:45
```

web server is nginx, config file:

```
location /static {
    alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
}

# Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
location /static/admin {
   alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
}
```

I also changed the second address to :

```
alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static/admin;
```

but still not working. (I use digital ocean as hosting)

- I did not edited the admin template
- I used `collectstatic` command in production version
- Checked it with different browsers
- Version of django is 1.11 in both server and local

So do I have to do something else after doing `collectstatic` ?

Comment: You are right, there is something wrong with the static files. But it hard to tell you what since it depends on how you deployed it. Also check your browsers debugger to see which requests actually failed.

Comment: Can you update with more info? It'd be helpful to see your settings.py static files config and to know how you deployed it.

Comment: @Daniel I added some extra information.

Comment: @KlausD. it fails on loading some files like jquery.js from admin static files. but I don't know the reason.

Comment: Nice, how about the hosting? Is it nginx? How it's configured? Post what shows in your browser console when accessing the admin site.

Comment: @Daniel console log added.

Comment: Still hard to guess, how is the hosting? What is the web server and how it's configured?

Comment: @Daniel web server is nginx and hosting is digital ocean (ubuntu 16.04). also more information added to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `collectstatic` command copies static files from admin site and other packages to your static directory so you don't need the second `location` block shown in your question.

Also change

```
location /static {
    alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
}
```

For

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/django/django_project/django_project;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, now you need to set permissions for your static/admin directory which has created after collectstatic command.In your root directory of the project (On production), run the following command.

sudo chown -R user:www-data static

Where user = Your current user of the system.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I think it's not the solution, I did it for both static and admin folder but didn't worked. Also my own static files serve properly and only problem is about admin panel.

Comment: You should not set the owner of the files to the actual user running the server for security reasons.